# Uploading multiply files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, loops, upload

Recently I got a problem with uploading multiply files by PHP.
Somewhere I saw some guide how to do it, so finally I ended up like this:

```
$total = count($_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]);
$target = "gallery/";
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
        if(($_FILES['ufile']['type'][$i]== 'image/jpeg')
        ||($_FILES['ufile']['type'][$i]== 'image/gif')
        ||($_FILES['ufile']['type'][$i]== 'image/png')
        &&($_FILES['ufile']['size'][$i]<2097152)
        &&($_FILES['ufile']['error'][$i] == 0)) {
                $image = $_FILES['ufile']["name"][$i];
                $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['ufile']["name"][$i]);
                $gallery_img[$i] = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp); //gallery is ready
                $final_gallery[$i] = $gallery_img[$i] . ", ";
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']["tmp_name"][$i], $target . $gallery_img[$i]);
                $wszystko_OK = true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunetly it doesn't work. I have no idea how to repair that code. Is it even possible to do operations with $_FILES in Array? I'm new into PHP so if you can explain how to possibly do it.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES['ufile']["name"][$i]);
$gallery_img[$i] = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
```

^this code is of course for making random filename to not make any collisions between them.

```
$final_gallery[$i] = $gallery_img[$i] . ", ";
```

^this actually is to collect all these filenames to variable. I want it to look like this:

> 1502916633.png, 1502916893.png, 1502916926.jpg

Then I would insert this variable into my MySQL database and then read this, delete comma sign and display multiply images. 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is one problem in your code, you're defining `$total` with `[$i]`, when `$i` hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: I thought I define $i, when I make loop.

Comment: That's not how PHP works.  You need to define `$i` before you use it.  The loop executes after you define `$total`.

Comment: Ok, now it's working, but in the folder with images, I have only one of them (I choosed three images) However, in the database instead of bunch of random filenames I've got only "Array".

Answer (score 0):

You define $i inside the for() statement. So, before it's undefined. Use count($_FILES['ufile']); to define $total.

Answer (score 0):

Having in count the pasted code, you should change:

```
$total = count($_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]);
```

by this:

```
$total = count($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use below code to count total files

```html
<?php
  $total = count($_FILES);
  ?>
```

Comment: Okay, I changed the code, but anyway, I got only one file in the folder. However, in the database instead of bunch of random filenames I've got only "Array".

Comment: just change in your code , use this 100 % sure
 $total =  count($_FILES['ufile']['name']);